# Pi 4 not booting up after being unplugged

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I have a raspberry pi 4 Model B which I was using via VNC when it suddenly froze. I was also connected to it via ssh and tried shutting it down but nothing worked so I unplugged it from the power source. After I plugged it in again it doesn't connect to the WiFi, neither it powers the fingerprint sensor that was working before, so I'm guessing it isn't booting the way it should. What can I do?

I do not know what to do since I'm on a trip and don't have neither a micro sd nor a micro hdmi with me.

Comment: In my experience, the SD cards that ship with Raspberry Pis are, well, crap. I must've had 5 or 6 die on me so far. 

Aside from that, pulling the plug without first shutting down is a pretty good way to trash your SD-card.

Traveling or not, you will probably have to buy a new SD-card and card reader. You can preconfigure all the SSH stuff when installing Raspberry Pi OS to the card and, if you're lucky, recover whatever you need from the other SD card with the card reader.